# What are typical track lighting track profiles used in Europe?

Tags: standard, lighting

In the U.S., the [typical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Track_lighting) track lighting track profiles are known as "H", "J" and "L". Their cross-sections can be easily found by googling them.

Are these same cross-sections used in Europe? If not, what cross-sections are used, and are there any standards that give the dimensions? As much as I can figure out, IEC 60570 unfortunately doesn't give standard track profile dimensions, only general requirements that place limits on some dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two "standards" I know of.

One is the professional three-phase system used by *ERCO*, *Staff*, *Zumtobel*, *Eutrac* and *Global*. Other companies are selling lamps for the system, too, it's widely used in shop-window and architecture lighting. Rails may differ in outer dimensions and are generally not compatible to each other.

The other "standard" is the much simpler Urail system introduced by Paulmann, which is sold in hardware stores.

Comment: Does anyone anywhere have inside dimensions of Paulmann's Urail?

Comment: I presume that even though the 3-phase rail outside dimensions may differ, the inside dimensions are fixed and thus 3-phase lamps will work with any 3-phse rail from ERCO, etc., right?

Comment: Haven't found a drawing about the Paulmann system, sorry. I think it would be easiest when you order a rail connector on the net. They are about 10€. Shipping would be expensive of course.

Comment: 3-phase: yes, the inside dimensions are all the same, so all lamps fit on all rails. But most lamps are one-phase only. Usually they have a small switch at the hanger 1-2-3-off, where you can connect them to one of the three phases. So, one rail for different lighting situations in the shop window (e.g. daylight/evening/night).